# Jquery.on method returns undefined is not a function

Tags: javascript

My goal was to create a simple button which once clicked would hide/show a navigational menu, and change the footer's padding alternatively, I'd have used toggle if not for the latter condition. Before I inserted `.on()` I just had the `.click()` method with a if/else, which only worked for the first click, so I added `.on` to solve the problem. Unfortunately it doesn't work, each time the console prints `'Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function'`. Any help, suggestions, or alternatives, will be much appreciated.

```
(function ($, Drupal){
Drupal.behaviors.footerCollapse = {
    attach : function() {
        function collapseOrCondense(event){
            if($('#block-panels-mini-footer-nice-menu:visible')){
            $('#footer').css({'padding-bottom':'2.5%'});
            $('#block-panels-mini-footer-nice-menu').hide();
         }
          else{
            $('#footer').css({'padding-bottom':'5.5%'});
            $('#block-panels-mini-footer-nice-menu').show();
          }
        };
        $('#footer').append('<button type=button class=cbutton>*</button>');
        $('#footer .cbutton').css({'position':'absolute', 'left':'1%', 'top':'1%', 'width':'2%','height':'1.5%'});
PROBLEM: $('#footer .cbutton').on('click',collapseOrCondense);
  }
 }
})(jQuery, Drupal);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

depending on the version of Drupal you are running, it is likely a jquery version issue. Drupal 7 for example defaults with jQuery 1.4 if memory serves, and .on() was added to jQuery in version 1.7.

You could try [jQuery Update](https://www.drupal.org/project/jquery_update) module:

> ```
> Upgrades the version of jQuery in Drupal core to a newer version of jQuery.
>
> Drupal 5 to jQuery 1.2.6
>
> Drupal 6 to jQuery 1.3.2
>
> Drupal 7 to jQuery 1.5.x, 1.7.x, 1.8.x, 1.9.x, 1.10.x and jQuery UI 1.10.2
>
> Drupal 8: TBD
> ```

Comment: downloaded the module which updated my jquery to 1.10 but now my colorbox modals don't seem to work, and I receive the error Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'version' of undefined Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'msie' of undefined VM6804 jquery.bgiframe.js?v=2.1:11. This also seems to impact the jquery on the rest of the site as well.

Comment: Seems to be a problem with the modal iframes, does jquery 1.10 not support iframes?

Comment: it should. The problem is that as versions increase, older functions are removed, so modules based on older versions of jquery might not work. This is a common problem. you could try only going to 1.7 instead of 1.10, or use something other than .on() for your needs

Comment: Reverted back to 1.7 and everything works, except on(), i'll try using delegate() instead

Comment: well seems as though on() does get processed, but it doesn't work in my favor. Basically my problem still remains the button only works once, thanks for the continued assistance, you answered this question, so I'll create another to try to determine the way in which the button can serve my purpose. Thank You :)

Comment: make sure there isn't a typo in your code: one() acts as on() but only allows it to run once.

Comment: what is the purpose of the button if you use the #footer selector for the .on() functionality?

Comment: That's a typo I accidentally inputted into the textfield, just rectified it, is suppose to be $('#footer .cbutton'), thanks for noticing. If you're interested my problem was attempting to use a selector as a boolean value ``if($('#block-panels-mini-footer-nice-menu:visible'))``, this was answered here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25879413/jquery-button-only-works-once. Thanks for the continued assistance :)